# Change amount of columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .txt file with a single line and many numbers separated by a variable amount of spaces.

```
32 45 2.65   -845     1 -84    97.236        454   35.78 77.12    948.87       
         151    -23.5         -787.48     13.005   31
```

I know every x numbers (being x a fix amount in every file) there should be a break. For instance the first 4 numbers in 4 columns the first row, next 4 the second row and so on.

```
+-------+---------+--------+------+
| col1  |  col2   |  col3  | col4 |
+-------+---------+--------+------+
| 32    | 45      | 2.65   | -845 |
| 1     | -84     | 97.236 |  454 |
| 35.78 | 77.12   | 948.87 |  151 |
| -23.5 | -787.48 | 13.005 |   31 |
+-------+---------+--------+------+
```

The objective is to create a .csv file with the right amount of columns.
So far I have been able to separate the numbers:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(table, sep='\s{2,}', header = None, engine='python')
export = data.to_csv(csvtable, header=False)
```

This creates a csv with one row and as many columns as values but I'd like to have the data in a specific amount of columns, 4 in this case.

Comment: Best way would be to read the original file as str, replace multiple spaces with single space using regex re.sub('\s+',' ', string_value), save it and read it again using pandas for DF.

Comment: Basically, I mean change the structure of the complete string and then use pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create list of all possible values from file, then reshape by numpy.reshape for 4 columns DataFrame:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    L = [x for line in f for x in line.strip().split()]
    print (L)
['32', '45', '2.65', '-845', '1', '-84', '97.236', '454', 
 '35.78', '77.12', '948.87', '151', '-23.5', '-787.48', '13.005', '31']


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(L).reshape(-1, 4))
print (df)
       0        1       2     3
0     32       45    2.65  -845
1      1      -84  97.236   454
2  35.78    77.12  948.87   151
3  -23.5  -787.48  13.005    31
```

But solution not working, if not possible create full 4 columns, then it is a bit complicated:

```
#missing last value
print (L)
['32', '45', '2.65', '-845', '1', '-84', '97.236', '454', '35.78', 
 '77.12', '948.87', '151', '-23.5', '-787.48', '13.005']

arr = np.empty(((len(L) - 1)//4 + 1)*4, dtype='O')
arr[:len(L)] = L
df = pd.DataFrame(arr.reshape((-1, 4))).fillna('0')
print(df)
       0        1       2     3
0     32       45    2.65  -845
1      1      -84  97.236   454
2  35.78    77.12  948.87   151
3  -23.5  -787.48  13.005     0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would load the data using Numpy

```
import numpy
import pandas

data = numpy.loadtxt('temp.txt').reshape(-1, 4)
pandas.DataFrame(data)
```

Edit: Swapped -1 and 4.

Comment: reshape(4, -1) will output 4 rows, not 4 columns.

Comment: This is a simpler approach, however as @JānisŠ. suggested, it should be reshape(-1, 4). That's why I accepted the other answer. +1 anyway, thank you!

Comment: Correct! I got confused by the fact that the test data had both 4 rows and columns.